# How could I define the seasons of the year in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have numeric values that refer to months of the year. ie january=1 february=2...
How could I define a function that returns these month values to the season of the year? Is it some kind of 'if' function?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, `if`s can achieve that. Try it and post the code if you've got doubts.

Comment: Consider using ```dict``` inside that function ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, simply use an if statement, or dict.

```
def season(month, northern_hemisphere):
    if month in [12,1,2]:
        return 'winter' if northern_hemisphere else 'summer'
    if month in [3, 4, 5]:
        return 'spring' if norther_hemisphere else 'autumn'
    if month in [6,7,8]:
        return 'summer if nothern_hemisphere else 'winter'
    if month in [9,10,11]:
        return 'autumn' if northern_hemisphere else 'spring'
    return None
```

Alternatively, you can use a clever lookup:

```
def season(month):
    return ['winter', 'spring','summer','autumn'][round((month % 12) / 3, 0)]
```